# Rollback after saving changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller and a repository. using EF 6

Controller file

```
int userID = _myrepository.addCustomer(model)
```

I get the userID

then using third party plugin to make a payment (ex:)

```
var success = makePaymentThroughPaymentProcessor(userID);
```

Now if the payment does not go through or an error happens I would like to rollback the changes so no customer is added not added to database.

I have tried using wrapping the repository method with

```
(var transaction = objMCOEntities.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
//code...
context.SaveChanges();
return userID;
```

I look over https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

but I'm not sure how to reference the transaction after addCustomer repository methods has been called

I could take the payment first and then add the customer to the db after but if an error happens while adding the customer to db then customer is not created but the payment will be made and then I would have to refund customer

Comment: why not just add the customer and delete it if the payment failed?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I think that just might be the easiest way to go, but I though there might be a more elegant way.

Comment: I think this will help you more than any thing http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/sortinganditerating/article.php/c10993/SystemTransactions-Implement-Your-Own-Resource-Manager.htm#page-2

Comment: Unless You commit the transaction none Your changes will affect the database. If an error occurs everything will be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework 6, you could have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) page. Basically you'll have to choose between tranaction.Commit() and transaction.Rollback();

But I don't think this is really necessary in this scenario. If you have the right sequence in your code (first payment via third party tool and then save to db), you don't exactly need a transaction, but I don't know the specifics of this third party tool.

Comment: Yes I'm using EF 6, reading the page but I'm not sure how to reference the transaction after addCustomer repository methods has been called.

Comment: Couldn't you wrap the addCustomer method inside the transaction instead of inside your repository method?